# Trouble selecting item from dropdown options using IE

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm trying to click on the dropdown option and select any item out of them but the clicking event is not being executed. As soon as the browser hits the line containing `elem.click` it throws an error `object variable or with block variable not set`. How can I mend my below effort to make it a go? Thanks in advance for any solution.

What I have tried so far is this:

```
Dim Hdoc as HTMLDocument, elem as object, s_item as object

Set Hdoc = IE.Document    ''here IE as New InternetExplorer
Set elem = Hdoc.getElementById("select")
elem.Click     ''error thrown here showing Object variable or with block ----

For Each s_item In Hdoc.getElementsByTagName("option")
    If InStr(1, s_item.innerText, "Asia Pacific Ex-Japan Fund", 1) > 0 Then s_item.Click: Exit For
Next s_item
```

Elements within which select button and dropdown options are embedded:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <select id="select" name="select" onchange="redirect(this.value);" style="width: 165px;">
   <option value="">
    Select a fund
   </option>
   <option value="/wps/myportal/mfs/non-us-advisor/products/meridian-funds/!ut/p/a1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOL9A40C_c09jAzcjYOdDYxcTPyNTUONDS1NjPW99KPSc_KTwEojHfOSjC3S9aOKUtNSi1KL9DLyi0v0I8rLy_Vy04r1kvNz9cOd9aMCEjMLMxz1C7KjkiodFRUBO3AG8w!!/dl5/d5/L2dJQSEvUUt3QS80SmlFL1o2X09RMlFPN0gyMEczU0MwMkQ0TzM1VTMxRk8y/?clearPortletSession=true&amp;productId=480&amp;shareId=33&amp;viewMode=profile">
    <!-- Do Nothing -->
    Absolute Return Fund
   </option>
   <option value="/wps/myportal/mfs/non-us-advisor/products/meridian-funds/!ut/p/a1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOL9A40C_c09jAzcjYOdDYxcTPyNTUONDS1NjPW99KPSc_KTwEojHfOSjC3S9aOKUtNSi1KL9DLyi0v0I8rLy_Vy04r1kvNz9cOd9aMCEjMLMxz1C7KjkiodFRUBO3AG8w!!/dl5/d5/L2dJQSEvUUt3QS80SmlFL1o2X09RMlFPN0gyMEczU0MwMkQ0TzM1VTMxRk8y/?clearPortletSession=true&amp;productId=1466&amp;shareId=33&amp;viewMode=profile">
    <!-- Do Nothing -->
    Asia Pacific Ex-Japan Fund
   </option>
   <option value="/wps/myportal/mfs/non-us-advisor/products/meridian-funds/!ut/p/a1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOL9A40C_c09jAzcjYOdDYxcTPyNTUONDS1NjPW99KPSc_KTwEojHfOSjC3S9aOKUtNSi1KL9DLyi0v0I8rLy_Vy04r1kvNz9cOd9aMCEjMLMxz1C7KjkiodFRUBO3AG8w!!/dl5/d5/L2dJQSEvUUt3QS80SmlFL1o2X09RMlFPN0gyMEczU0MwMkQ0TzM1VTMxRk8y/?clearPortletSession=true&amp;productId=139597&amp;shareId=33&amp;viewMode=profile">
    <!-- Do Nothing -->
    Blended Research European Equity Fund
   </option>
   <option value="/wps/myportal/mfs/non-us-advisor/products/meridian-funds/!ut/p/a1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOL9A40C_c09jAzcjYOdDYxcTPyNTUONDS1NjPW99KPSc_KTwEojHfOSjC3S9aOKUtNSi1KL9DLyi0v0I8rLy_Vy04r1kvNz9cOd9aMCEjMLMxz1C7KjkiodFRUBO3AG8w!!/dl5/d5/L2dJQSEvUUt3QS80SmlFL1o2X09RMlFPN0gyMEczU0MwMkQ0TzM1VTMxRk8y/?clearPortletSession=true&amp;productId=3014&amp;shareId=33&amp;viewMode=profile">
    <!-- Do Nothing -->
    Continental European Equity Fund
   </option>
   <option value="/wps/myportal/mfs/non-us-advisor/products/meridian-funds/!ut/p/a1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOL9A40C_c09jAzcjYOdDYxcTPyNTUONDS1NjPW99KPSc_KTwEojHfOSjC3S9aOKUtNSi1KL9DLyi0v0I8rLy_Vy04r1kvNz9cOd9aMCEjMLMxz1C7KjkiodFRUBO3AG8w!!/dl5/d5/L2dJQSEvUUt3QS80SmlFL1o2X09RMlFPN0gyMEczU0MwMkQ0TzM1VTMxRk8y/?clearPortletSession=true&amp;productId=165855&amp;shareId=33&amp;viewMode=profile">
    <!-- Do Nothing -->
    Diversified Income Fund
   </option>
  </select>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the `click` method of the `elem` object fails because there is no `elem` ebject

Answer (score 0):

Can you please run this - i think it's because the Hdoc hasn't had time to set

```
    Dim Hdoc As HTMLDocument, elem As Object, s_item As Object

    Set Hdoc = IE.Document    ''here IE as New InternetExplorer
    Set elem = Hdoc.getElementById("select")
    Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    elem.Click     ''error thrown here showing Object variable or with block ----

    For Each s_item In Hdoc.getElementsByTagName("option")
        If InStr(1, s_item.innerText, "Asia Pacific Ex-Japan Fund", 1) > 0 Then s_item.Click: Exit For
    Next s_item
```

Comment: I ran your suggested portion and found that the script threw the same error upon hitting the specific line I mentioned in my post. That is why `MsgBox` never shows up. Thanks.

Comment: @Topto it's probably because `elem` hasn't been set (this can happen with multi-threading) - I've updated the code which should sort this

Comment: @Topto I think I know what's wrong - by the looks of the snippet of code you have above it looks like you're using a HTTP request.. if this is the case, then the '.Click' function won't work because that's an Internet explorer function so you'll need to approach this as an IE simulation, rather then an (`Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`) Can you show all you're code?

Comment: Please don't judge me hypothetically. Here is how i started: `Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL
        Do While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set HTMLDoc = .document
    End With`